# Clip Path has 1px single line separating sections?

Tags: html, css

So I have a clip path to create a downward arrow between the sections. In other words, I have gradient on section 1, and then a gradient on section 2. In section 2, I've clip-pathed it so that it looks like a downward arrow that is connected to the first section.

What doesn't make sense, is that this code is the same for all the other sections (with differnet id's obviously), but it's showing properly. At the top of section 2, it has a 1px line that's visible (and showcases the different sections) as not being connected. But the problem isn't anywhere else. I've cleared cache, attempted to change the code, and even used the dev tools. Nothing is working. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the image so you can see what it looks like: 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
#divider-red-section-3 {
position: relative;
background-size: cover;
background-color: $white-bg;
height: 15rem;
width: auto;

.primary-overlay-4 {
background: $primary-what-amidoing-overlay;
position: absolute;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 30%, 50% 100%, 0 30%, 0 0, 100% 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 30%, 50% 100%, 0 30%, 0 0, 100% 0);
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

}

Comment: Can share HTML code too, so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: make it top:-1px and you are good

Comment: Thanks that worked Temani!!